# Add button in sonata admin clear jQuery on sonata_type_collection : sonata-collection-item-added

Tags: jquery, json, symfony, autocomplete, sonata-admin

I implemented autocomplete field in my form with sonata admin.

This form (ScheduleAdmin) has a collection of games (GamesAdmin).

My problem is that I can't use jQuery. In fact, when a Add a new form of type Games my jQuery isn't launched.

But when I edit a Schedule who had Games my autocomplete field works... only the first one

**EDIT :**

There is no way to use this tip :

TIP: A jQuery event is fired after a row has been added (sonata-collection-item-added) or deleted (sonata-collection-item-deleted). You can bind to these events to trigger custom javascript imported into your templates (eg: add a calendar widget to a newly added date field)

[Source](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-collection)

I'm a noob in JQuery and I don't know how to bind this element.

Someone can help ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.

I've fix it with the [GenumFormBundle](https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle%22GenemuFormBundle%22).

Install it with composer like: *composer.json*

```
{
    "require": {
        "_some_packages": "...",

        "genemu/form-bundle": "2.1.*" => for Symfony 2.1 and 2.2

        "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*" => for Symfony 2.3
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the bundle into the **AppKernel.php** and the run the assetic command:

```
$ php app/console assets:install web/
```

After that you can use it into the Admin class with:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{      
// ...   
    $formMapper
        ->with('General')
          ->add('sample_choice', 'genemu_jqueryautocompleter_choice', array(
                     'choices' => array(
                        'Choice 1' => 'Choice 1',
                        'Choice 2' => 'Choice 2',
                        'n.a.' => 'Not available'
                    )))
```

See the documentation which autocomplete field types are available.
You can also choice entity. But notice that only the id of the database entry gets returned at the form and not the value!

Usage in filter modus:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
    // ...
        ->add('customer',  null, array(), 'genemu_jqueryautocompleter_entity')
    // ...
```

Notice: You have to add the following line into your layout:

```
{{ form_stylesheet(form) }}
and
{{ form_javascript(form) }}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer ! I tried to use genemuFormBundle but it seems that it's doesn't work... There is a specific template configuration for sonata and genemu ?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure but by default the option should be available if the genemu bundle is loaded correctly.
Notice: It doesn't work in ajax popup window. Seems there is an issue while loading the necessary header files or gets in conflict with other jquery libs.

Comment: See my update above. You have to add {{ form_stylesheet(form) }} and
{{ form_javascript(form) }} in your main layout twig file.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know why it doesn't work for me... I try to implement the chosen jquery library but I don't konw how to bind : **sonata-collection-item-added**. Any idea ?

Comment: Sorry it's hard to answer without any code. But does the genemu bundle is loaded and visible after you input some text in your textfield. Try it for testing on an other field to see it is generally working...

Comment: Thank for help, I restart my project with symfony 2.3 and it works ! Maybe a conflict in the 2.2 version... I don't know.

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah this a good idea if possible with the project. I also migrate most of my 2.2 projects to 2.3.